# How to auto generate HTML page from a text file?

Tags: html, web, auto-generate

I have a text file named `info.txt` and I want to generate a HTML page that shows its contents. How can I achieve it?

Text file:

```
Year : 2012
Name : Dragons
Size : 250mb
```

Expected HTML output:

```
Year of Realese : 2012
Name of the Show : Dragons
Size : 250
```

Comment: What platform are you using? Asp, PHP, JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a key:value  pair, you can save it as a json file use xmlhttpresponse to read json and create html elements. But xmlhttpresponse requires you to have a server running, it won't work locally. Read about json and how to access them using Javascript. It's very simple.